# Apache hive MSCK REPAIR TABLE new partition not added

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-hive

I am new for Apache Hive. While working on external table partition, if I add new partition directly to HDFS, the new partition is not added after running MSCK REPAIR table. Below are the codes I tried,

-- creating external table

```
hive> create external table factory(name string, empid int, age int) partitioned by(region string)  
    > row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

--Detailed Table Information

```
Location:  hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/warehouse/factory     
Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE           
Table Parameters:        
    EXTERNAL                TRUE                
    transient_lastDdlTime   1438579844
```

-- creating directory in HDFS to load data for table factory

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -mkdir 'hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/testing/testing1/factory1'
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -mkdir 'hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/testing/testing1/factory2'
```

-- Table data

```
cat factory1.txt
emp1,500,40
emp2,501,45
emp3,502,50

cat factory2.txt
EMP10,200,25
EMP11,201,27
EMP12,202,30
```

-- copying from local to HDFS

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal '/home/cloudera/factory1.txt' 'hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/testing/testing1/factory1'
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal '/home/cloudera/factory2.txt' 'hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/testing/testing1/factory2'
```

-- Altering table to update in the metastore

```
hive> alter table factory add partition(region='southregion') location '/user/hive/testing/testing1/factory2';
hive> alter table factory add partition(region='northregion') location '/user/hive/testing/testing1/factory1';            
hive> select * from factory;                                                                      
OK
emp1    500 40  northregion
emp2    501 45  northregion
emp3    502 50  northregion
EMP10   200 25  southregion
EMP11   201 27  southregion
EMP12   202 30  southregion
```

Now I created new file factory3.txt to add as new partition for the table factory

```
cat factory3.txt
user1,100,25
user2,101,27
user3,102,30
```

-- creating the path and copying table data

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -mkdir 'hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/testing/testing1/factory2'
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal '/home/cloudera/factory3.txt' 'hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/testing/testing1/factory3'
```

now I executed the below query to update the metastore for the new partition added

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE factory;
```

Now the table is not giving the new partition content of factory3 file. Can I know where I am doing mistake while adding partition for table factory?

whereas, if I run the alter command then it is showing the new partition data.

```
hive> alter table factory add partition(region='eastregion') location '/user/hive/testing/testing1/factory3';
```

Can I know why the MSCK REPAIR TABLE command is not working?

Answer (score 16):

For the `MSCK` to work, naming convention `/partition_name=partition_value/` should be used. For example in the root directory of table;

```
# hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/root_of_table/*
 /user/hive/root_of_table/day=20200101/data1.parq
 /user/hive/root_of_table/day=20200101/data2.parq
 /user/hive/root_of_table/day=20200102/data3.parq
 /user/hive/root_of_table/day=20200102/data4.parq
```

When you run `msck repair table <tablename>` partitions of `day`; `20200101` and `20200102` will be added automatically.

Comment: didn't understand, what if there are 1000s of values ?

Comment: Added example to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put data in directory named 'region=eastregio' in table location directory:

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir 'hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/warehouse/factory/region=eastregio'
$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal '/home/cloudera/factory3.txt' 'hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/warehouse/factory/region=eastregio'
```

Comment: What if the partition directories are empty?